# how to download multiple files from a path or a folder in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

hi i am trying to download multiple files from a location path that path having multiple folder each folder contain one file .

```vb
For j = 0 To dst.Rows.Count - 1
    FILEPATH = (dst.Rows(i)("Filepath").ToString())

    Response.ContentType = ContentType
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", ("attachment; filename=" + Path.GetFileName(FILEPATH)))
    Response.WriteFile(FILEPATH)
    Response.Flush()
    Response.ClearHeaders()
    Response.End()
Next
```

this is the code i am using for downloading files .But issue is only one file i am able to download

Comment: Can you elaborate on the problem a bit more?

Comment: @LajosArpad actual issue is when i am trying to download the file from a folder path .It is working fine when there is one folder and one file .But i am trying to work it for multiple files to download at a time so for that purpose i am using the loop but this piece of code isn't working

Comment: Can you explain how it is not working?

Comment: its not working for multiple file .On response.end() its giving exception saying thread was being aborted and it coming out of loop .

Comment: And what happens if you move `Response.End()` after the loop?

Comment: After removing response.end() the  Response.AppendHeader is getting expectation saying that ** server cannot append header after http headers have been sent**

Comment: And what happens if you move the call for `AppendHeader()` outside the loop (but before the call to `End()`)?

Comment: no same issue its not working as expected

Comment: Can you answer in a more detailed manner? I can only help if you are willing to provide the information I need in order to do so.